# How to store attachments to local filesystem on 7.0?

Tags: odoo

I've been struggling with configuring my server to store all attachments to local filesystem instead of a database. How do you do that on OpenERP 7.0 server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to configure the local storage for attachments has changed in OpenERP v7. The new system is summarized in this [post](http://help.openerp.com/question/529/where-are-document-attachments-stored/).

By default attachments are stored in the database, but you may choose to store them on the filesystem by setting a System Parameter (via Settings > Technical > Parameters > System Parameters) named `ir_attachment.location`. In order to see this menu you need the "Technical Features" access right.

This parameter should have the format: `protocol://URI`, and the only supported protocol by default is the local `file://`, for example `file:///filestore`

Note that the path for the `file://` protocol is taken relative to the OpenERP root path (location of the OpenERP server), so with `ir_attachment.location` set to `file:///filestore` the attachments will be stored at under at `<root_path>/filestore`.

The new system also uses a SHA1 hash to generate the filename, so that duplicate files don't take any space.

In database mode the file contents is stored in the `ir_attachment.db_datas` column.
In filestore mode the file name is stored in the `ir_attachment.db_datas_fname` column.
(The cryptic names are for backwards compatibility)

**Warning:** No automatic conversion mechanism exists between storage mechanisms. This means that:

- When you set this parameter existing attachments remain stored in the database, only *new* ones will be stored in the filesystem. The system will try both locations so it's not a problem (first looking for database storage, then filesystem storage).
- If you remove this parameter you should manually store back the files in the database because the system will only look in the database.